# Control posts back http request, how do I get it? (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

Request["ControlName"] doesn't work because I have been told the control is probably in a container... so how do I get the http request? The FORM part of the Request starts like this:

{__EVENTTARGET=ctl00%24lstThemeChooser&__EVENTARGUMENT=&__LASTFOCUS=&__VIEWSTATE=%2fwEP

lstThemeChooser is the name of my control...

Blue Theme
            Orange Theme

defined in my masterpage aspx file

Comment: Do you mean you just want to know, server-side, which control caused the postback?

Comment: I want to get the value of the dropdownbox on my masterpage, on any page that is using the masterpage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attention! Pseudocode!

```
public interface IMyMasterPage
{
   string ThemeChooserID { get; }
}

public partial class MyMasterPage : MasterPage, IMyMasterPage
{
    public string ThemeChooserID { get { return lstThemeChooser.ClientID; } }
}

public MyPage : Page
{
    protected void Page_PreInit(...)
    {
        string id = ((IMyMasterPage)this.Master).ThemeChooserID;
        string val = Request[id];
    }
}
```

Comment: Very cunning but unfortunately lstThemeChooser cannot be found in the master page.. I guess it cannot access its own stuff directly like that...

Comment: Perhaps I can make an event handler or something to update a static variable?

Comment: where is lstThemeChooser  then defined?

Comment: It's in the master page, along with the header stuff. Edited question to include definition

Comment: If it's defined in the MasterPages.master file then you can access it in the MasterPage.master.cs file. There you can expose the ClientID of this control as a Property.

Comment: Hmm, it is defined in there, perhaps there is a reason why it is invisible?

Comment: maybe there is something wrong with intenseness? Just try it and compile.

Comment: Error 5 The name 'lstThemeChooser' does not exist in the current context C:\backups\140909backup\backup\main site\AdminPages\MasterPages\AdminSystem.Master.cs 18 56

Comment: can you please edit your question and paste the masterpage + sourcecode?

Comment: master page is huge, but I see what you mean - I created a new blank master page and added a control, and I could access it. In the designer file for the blank master page, I could see the definition for the control... but my main master page, the designer file is empty...! Not sure why, but I guess declaring it in there will fix it. I shall try it.

Comment: It occurs to me that I probably HAVE to use the postback since I am using this on the pre-render method, the control won't exist to get the value of...

Comment: I have a solution. I basically get the entire eventstate, and parse it with some substrings to get the data I want out. I can see it in there, I just can't figure out what to put intot he Request[] to get it. I am tired of this ridiculous problem so I am just going to write a nasty hack to solve it. Welcome to asp.net...

Comment: Do I understand that right? You are creating the control in OnPreRender? If so, then I would suggest to place the Control simply in the Masterpage. ASP.NET is doing the rest for you (except in PreInit).

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET prepends the container to the control name, so your control on the page is called **ctl00%24lstThemeChooser**.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Request[lstThemeChooser.ClientID]
```

Comment: without quotes, I get lstThemeChooser does not exist in the current context. That's in a pre-init method on my page.

Comment: Also it would be better to specify the collection when using a Request object.

Comment: Ah - yes, because it's in your MasterPage. Try to expose this ClientID  in MasterPage as Property. Code sample will follow in a new Answer